# EGL linker errors

Tags: g++, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I'm trying to link a really simple GLES2 & EGL program using g++ 4.9.1, on a Ubuntu Trusty system. I'm using the mesa libraries.

I'm getting linker errors for EGL functions:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `eglGetDisplay'
test.cpp:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to `eglInitialize'
test.cpp:(.text+0x40f): undefined reference to `eglCreateContext'
test.cpp:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `eglCreatePbufferSurface'
test.cpp:(.text+0x49e): undefined reference to `eglMakeCurrent'
```

I am compiling test.cpp with

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -lEGL -lGLESv2 -o test test.cpp
```

I've tried switching the order of libraries, which sometimes matters, but I get the same problem. Is there a library I'm missing here?

I've run `readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so` and all of the required functions are defined.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix this by compiling the C++ file to an object file, and then linking as a separate step. I'm not sure why this works, when the one-line compilation doesn't.

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -c -o test.o test.cpp 
g++ -o test test.o -lGLESv2 -lEGL
```

I've put the question to the community to try to figure out why: [Single-command compile and link fails, separate steps work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655328/single-command-compile-and-link-fails-separate-steps-work)

Answer (score 5):

You should put libraries to the end of a command line

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -o test test.cpp -lEGL -lGLESv2
```