# gcc undefined reference to dbus_*

Tags: c, gcc

There is a lot of similar questions, but unfortunately they didn't help a lot.

I'm trying to build program from [this](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/d-bus-ipc-mechanism-linux/) post, and have an error:

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1` hh.c -o hh
/tmp/ccMabXOg.o: In function `main':
hh.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `dbus_error_init'
hh.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get'
hh.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
hh.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
hh.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_name_has_owner'
hh.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
hh.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
hh.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_request_name'
hh.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
hh.c:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is `include <dbus/dbus.h>`, and file present on the system:

```
# find / -name "dbus.h" -type f
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h
```

But `dbus_error_init` for example present in `dbus-errors.h` file:

```
# grep -r dbus_error_init /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-errors.h:void        dbus_error_init      (DBusError       *error);
```

I'm not C developer and not too much familiar with `gcc` and the linker, so any tips/links appreciated.

Comment: If you run `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1` alone, what's the output?

Comment: `$ pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1
-I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include  -ldbus-1`

Comment: You need to link your application to the dbus-1 library.

Comment: @JanHenke Thanks. Could you add this as an Answer?

Comment: That cannot be the answer (I removed my answer which said the same).  Look at what `pkg-config` is producing.  Perhaps the `pkg-config` is misplaced in the command line and needs to be at the end or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your linkage order is back-to-front. Instead of:

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1` hh.c -o hh
```

do:

```
gcc hh.c -o hh `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1`
```

or:

```
gcc hh.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1` -o hh
```

In the linkage sequence, files that need symbol definitions must come before the ones that provide the definitions. 
So libraries come after object files. If it is unclear how this applies to
your commandline read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28655328/1362568) and
my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The missing symbols are defined in the `dbus-1` library. You have to tell `gcc` to link to that library.
If you have the library installed in a default location on your system, the `-ldbus-1` flag should be enough to tell the linker to use that library in resolving the missing symbols.

Comment: But it apparently does not work with ```pkg-config```, since the undefined symbols mentioned by the OP are clearly defined by libdbus-1.so.3 on my system.

Comment: Understood; but you can see (from the comment) that `-ldbus-1` is already being emitted by `pkg-config`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example, and it built for me.

First of all, you're getting a linking error and not a compilation error so there's a problem finding your library.

Here's my library:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so

I'm running Devuan GNU/Linux 1.0 (jessie) which is similar Debian/Ubuntu.

1. How did you install your dbus library?

I got mine like this:

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libdbus-1-dev